# Merge two names /or just extract names from CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to read csv file containing different names and merge two names into one.
 for example:
google.com , facebook.com
should generate something like 
googleface.com or googlebook.com

```
import csv
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

ps = PorterStemmer()
with open('C:/Users/upadh/Desktop/domains.txt', 'r') as csvFile:
 csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
 string ={}
 count =0
     for row in csvReader:
    # for row in csvReader:
      #if row is 0 :
       for header, value in row.items():
          try:
              string[header].append(value)
          except KeyError:
              string[header] = [value]
    for w in sorted(str(string)):
       print(w, " : ", ps.stem(w))
```

Comment: show us what you tried so far.

Comment: till now i am trying to fetch the possible english names out of  domain name

Answer (score 0):

Extract names can be done like this:

```
import csv

with open('inputCSV.txt', 'r') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    for line in csvReader:
        #prints all 'names' in the csv file, here you can add code to do whatever. 
        [print(name) for name in line]
```

Comment: here is a link that might help as well https://realpython.com/python-csv/